# PBS/Torque test script not running successfully

Tags: torque

I am a newbie in the world of cluster management software. I installed PBS-Torque successfully but when i ran

```
qsub test.sh i get
```

18.localhost

I checked using qstat i found following status.

```
Job ID                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - ----
16.localhost               test.sh          user                 0 Q batch          
17.localhost               test.sh          user                 0 Q batch          
18.localhost               test.sh          user                 0 Q batch
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
do echo $i >> /home/user/output.txt;
done;
```

May i know where i am wrong?

Comment: What is it you think is wrong from what you're seeing? It looks correct to me.

Comment: Please note that SGE and PBS/Torque are not the same.